# How to remove the space at the end of a short listView?

Tags: java, android, listview

I was making use of ListView today for my project, and I need my list view to start from the button it was called from BUT as the usual list view behaves the items are usually presented on the top of the allocated space of it (on the screen) and when it  does that, it leaves unwanted space which I want to get rid of.

My ListView suppose to hold 1-4 items for showings and 2 more when scrolled.
So there are situations where the list itself is not full.

Is it possible to make my list view to do what I seek, and if so, how?

A visual example:
My current ListView looks like this:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
*unwanted space*
*Button that changes the visibillity of the list view*
```

I want my list view to look like the following if the list turns out short:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
*Button that changes the visibillity of the list view*
```

This is the XML of my listView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    tools:targetApi="11">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/chooserBtn"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/chooserBtn"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/chooserBtn"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where is code of button?

Comment: Show the code of listview_item. Probably you giving padding/margin from top or bottom that apply on last item as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah... I looked for a few more hours in the web and finally found a working solution.

These 3 lines in the xml needed to be added:

```
android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
android:stackFromBottom="true"
android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have to use "wrap_content" height of listview and the parent layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    tools:targetApi="11">
   <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/chooserBtn"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/chooserBtn"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/chooserBtn"
            android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
            android:headerDividersEnabled="false" />
<!-- or use button code here just make listview height as "wrap_content"-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I cannot change my hight to wrap content because I have restricted space which I must follow.